# Trying to validate email endings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Question: I am trying to validate email endings in an array

```js
let input = 'test@gmail.com' // This is grabbed dynamically but for sake of explanation this works the same

let validEndings = ['@gmail.com', '@mail.com', '@aol.com'] //and so on

if(input.endsWith(validEndings)){
  console.log('valid')
}else{
  console.log('invalid')
}
```

I can get this to work when validEndings is just a singular string e.g `let validEndings = '@gmail.com'`
but not when its in an array comparing multiple things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem with regex. Example:

```js
const input = 'test@gmail.com';
const validEndingsRegex = /@gmail.com$|@mail.com$|@aol.com$/g;
const found = input.match(validEndingsRegex);

if (found !== null) {
  console.log('valid')
} else {
  console.log('invalid')
}
```

Comment: I fixed your variable name and made it runnable

Comment: You still have a bug. `const input = 'test@mailXcom';`

Comment: Ah ive never used Regex very neat thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method which tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let input = 'test@gmail.com';

let validEndings = ['@gmail.com', '@mail.com', '@aol.com'];

const res = validEndings.some(endingStr => input.endsWith(endingStr));

console.log(res);
```